# XAMPP Wordpress create different wesbite under localhost

Tags: wordpress, xampp, localhost

[New Site Address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCmhM.png)

I am new to WordPress. Trying to use it to build 2-3 websites in localhost using different site address. For example:

Site A: http://localhost/siteA

Site B: http://localhost/siteB

But what I get is:

Site A: http://localhost/wordpress/siteA

Site B: http://localhost/wordpress/siteB

Is it possible to remove WordPress directory in URL? Thanks.

*Working environment:*

*The WordPress installation files are under localhost.*

*XAMPP V3.2.2*

*phpMyAdmin 4.8.2*

*WordPress 4.9.7*

Comment: Using XAMPP and PhpMyAdmin

Comment: You have to place all the wordpress files at the root of you project directory. i.e. if you have created a folder "siteA" for a new site, all you wordpress files should reside at the root location of "siteA". Same applies for any new directory you create for another site.

Comment: @zipkundan I did it before, but soon I found that different sites, siteA and siteB which holding each WordPress files under their root location, will mess up each other. When I go to the link "http://localhost/siteB/wp-admin", it will bring me to "http://localhost/siteA/wp-admin".

Comment: I found a solution just now....considering the suggestion that @zipkundan given......just put the WordPress installation file under localhost without creating new folder...and it works as what I wish.